# Issue with Gstreamer After Building from GIT Source

Tags: git, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have download the GIT repo of Gstreamer using following Command and Created Application Directory

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gstreamer
sudo mkdir -p /apps/gstreamer/git
```

Built the Source Code using Following commands

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure --prefix=/apps/gstreamer/git --enable-gtk-doc 
time make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Updated required Environment Variables as follows

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/apps/gstreamer/git/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/gstreamer/git/lib
export PATH=/apps/gstreamer/git/bin:$PATH
```

I can see `gst-launch-1.0` binary comes in my environment. Now I am using Following Pipeline

```
./gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

gives me following error

```
0:00:00.001778784 12428       0xc96ec0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "audiotestsrc"
0:00:00.001826395 12428       0xc96ec0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "audioconvert"
0:00:00.001839183 12428       0xc96ec0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:901:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@(nil)]
0:00:00.001859200 12428       0xc96ec0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "autoaudiosink"
0:00:00.001871881 12428       0xc96ec0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:901:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@(nil)]
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "audiotestsrc".
```

Can you please let me know which steps I am missing? Any Help is appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: ./gst-inspect-1.0 should tell you all the plugins/elements which are installed.  you have just installed the core library (base/good/bad/...) are still missing. (https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/)

Comment: Thanks Mate. Will look into it